# How to set a password to open an Excel 2007 document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

How to set an Excel password to protect a workbook from unauthorized access by setting a password on it?

I once saw an Excel document with a password required to open it. I found out how to do it and decided to share by asking this question and answering it.

Comment: This is a horrible way to secure a document. Brute force is trivial as only the hash needs to be cracked, not the password. You are better off using Windows ACLs for the file or share.

Comment: For many users in an office where passwords are merely used to prevent users making changes you don't intend, this is fine. It is however true that this is not effective security. BUT if it is simply to make it inconvenient to make permanent changes that is all some people want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if this works for other version of excel but i've tested in on excel 2007

Open your excel, type what you want to store

Click the Save As button, 
In the save as Dialog box, beside the save the save button, click the tool drop down

[image: Tools]

In the drop down menu, click General Options, you will see a dialog box, set the password there